# R Create Multiple New Variables

Tags: r, case, variable-assignment, across, mutate

I'm having trouble finding a solution for a complex variable assignment need.  I need to create new variables based on the values in existing variables, but I need to do the same new variable creation many times using a different set of existing variables each time.
So for example, I have the following data frame:

```
dat=data.frame(
kiwi_3=c(1,0,1),
kiwi_5=c(0,0,1),
kiwi_8=c(1,1,0),

apple_3=c(0,0,0),
apple_5=c(1,0,1),
apple_8=c(1,1,0))
```

I can use the following line of code to create a new variable based on values in existing variables:

```
dat<-dat %>%
  mutate(fruit_3=case_when(kiwi_3==1 & apple_3==1~1,
                            kiwi_3==1 & apple_3==0~2))
```

However, what I need to do is to create variables for each number suffix (in this example, fruit_3, fruit_5, fruit_8) based on the variables with the same (non-sequential) number suffix, using the same logic.  The actual logic is more complicated than in this example too so I would guess that using case_when will be necessary.  I imagine there's a solution using dplyr mutate and across, possibly with indexed vectors with the variable names in them, but I haven't hit upon a solution that works yet.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to work with column numbers and offsets.  Here is a half-baked example using `for` loops in which the paired values are simply multiplied together to generate the binary results, (assuming that if kiwi = 0 OR apple = 0 the result = 0:

```
dat=data.frame(
      kiwi_3=c(1,0,1),
      kiwi_5=c(0,0,1),
      kiwi_8=c(1,1,0),
      apple_3=c(0,0,0),
      apple_5=c(1,0,1),
      apple_8=c(1,1,0))

mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

for (i in 1:3) {
      for (j in 1:3) {
      mat[i, j] <- dat[i, j] * dat[i, j+3]
      }
}

cbind(dat, mat)
  kiwi_3 kiwi_5 kiwi_8 apple_3 apple_5 apple_8 1 2 3
1      1      0      1       0       1       1 0 0 1
2      0      0      1       0       0       1 0 0 1
3      1      1      0       0       1       0 0 1 0
```

Column names would also have to be added to the output matrix. This will work on it's own, but others may have ideas on how to refactor the approach using `dplyr`.

Comment: Thanks for this response!  Unfortunately, the fact that the values can be multiplied were an unintentional result as I simplified my actual case_when function. (I've fixed this above.)  Your suggestion of creating a matrix and using a for loop should work though but the code would be very complicated and prone to errors on my part, so I'm wondering if there is a dplyr approach as you suggested.  Thanks!